# How to set dynamic slug in Nuxt3 i18n module

Tags: nuxt.js, internationalization

I need to set dynamic slug for each language (NUXT3, i18n module):
https://v8.i18n.nuxtjs.org/guide/lang-switcher#dynamic-route-parameters

This works when I set it manually.

```
<script setup>
definePageMeta({
  // ...
  nuxtI18n: {
    en: { id: 'my-post' },
    fr: { id: 'mon-article' }
  }
  // ...
})
</script>
```

But when I try to set data fetched from API, there is error post is undefined.

```
<script setup>

const { data: post, pending, refresh } = await useAsyncData(
    'post',
    () => $fetch(`https://myapi.com/api/blog/${route.params.slug}`+'?locale='+locale.value)
)

definePageMeta({
  // ...
  nuxtI18n: {
    en: { id: post.en.slug },
    fr: { id: post.fr.slug }
  }
  // ...
})
</script>
```

It is possible to set object fetched from API instead of manually setting the slug?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `method: "POST"`?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm struggling with the same problem